# Layering Flash (100% width and height) over HTML: can't access HTML elements in Firefox/Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, flash

As the title suggests, when I layer an swf over html, with all the good stuff in place (wmode = transparent, z-index), I can't access the html elements in Firefox/Chrome/Safari.

Here's a link to a test http://www.erichboyer.com/test/test2.html

This is a stripped down version; I've also tried using swfobject.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are doing is possible. You can't click THROUGH any element, including flash. If something has a higher z-indx then the other elements on the page, and 100% width and height, nothing else on the page will be interactive.

Maybe you could solve your problem by putting the flash under the elements?
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/keep-flash-behind-other-elements/

Why do you need flash at all?
Why does it need 100% width and height?
Sound pretty messy, what you're doing.